# pandas: how to sort results of groupby using a pd.cut categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is an output from groupby using a categorical variable created by pd.cut.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

di = pd.DataFrame({'earnings':pd.np.random.choice(10000, 10000), 'counts':[1] * 10000})
brackets=append(np.arange(0,5001,500),100000000)
di['earncat']=pd.cut(di['earnings'], brackets,right=False,retbins=True)[0]

di_everyone=di.groupby('earncat').sum()[['counts']]
di_everyone.sort_index(inplace=True)
di_everyone.to_string
```

And this is the output,

```
[0, 500)          83,005,823
[1000, 1500)      11,995,255
[1500, 2000)      13,943,052
[2000, 2500)      11,967,696
[2500, 3000)      10,741,178
[3000, 3500)       9,749,914
[3500, 4000)       6,833,928
[4000, 4500)       7,150,125
[4500, 5000)       4,655,773
[500, 1000)        9,718,753
[5000, 100000000) 26,588,622
```

I'm not sure why [500, 1000)  appears on the second to last line. I decided to not label earncat because i want to see the breakdown. How can I sort on earncat?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? Starting from 0.16.1, there is support for Categorical variables in the index, which will do the sorting correctly

Comment: Your index is converted to strings before they are sorted. df_everyone.index shows Index([u'[0, 500)', ... So it is sorted on earncat. Just not the way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using pandas 0.15.x which does not support this kind of operation with categorical dtypes (which the pd.cut function produces)

In the meantime, you can work around the problem like this:

```
di['earnlower'] = di['earncat'].apply(lambda x: int(x[1:].split(',')[0]))
di['earnhigher'] = di['earncat'].apply(lambda x: int(x[:-2].split(',')[1]))

di_everyone=di.groupby(['earnlower', 'earnhigher']).sum()[['counts']]
```

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the latest pandas and it fixed the problem.